# How to add audio only when mousepressed in processing?

Tags: audio, processing

I was wondering if there was a processing code that will let me use sound only when i press the mouse and stops when I release it. I already have the audio that I want to use loaded onto processing but I'm having difficulty finding the code. Please help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is very vague, but I'll do my best to answer.

I don't think there's any way to handle audio with Processing's built-in functions, but the minim library works well with it. I'm going to assume that's what you're using for this solution.

As I understand it, you'd like to press the mouse, start the sound, and when the mouse is released you'd like to stop the sound, rather than pause it. We can accomplish this using processing's built-in mousePressed and mouseReleased methods like so:

```
import ddf.minim.*;

Minim minim;
AudioPlayer player;
AudioInput input;

void setup()
{
  //let's make the window a little bigger
  size(400,400);

  minim = new Minim(this);
  player = minim.loadFile("song.mp3");
  input = minim.getLineIn();
}

void draw(){ }

void mousePressed()
{
  player.play();
}

void mouseReleased()
{
  player.close();

  //since close closes the file, we'll load it again
  player = minim.loadFile("song.mp3");
}
```

The code for pausing would look very similar, except you would replace everything in the mouseReleased block with the following:

```
player.pause();
```

Comment: Are there any inbuilt sounds that one can use. 
I am looking to simulate a click sound on mouse click.